# Residuals against fitted values show pattern

Tags: r, statistics

I am going to fit a model using linear and quadratic model.
If the graphs of residuals against fitted values show pattern(not random pattern),what is the cause and how can i fix it?

Comment: this question probably belongs on [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com), but it's also too broad. If you show a *specific* example of what's going wrong, it might be possible to give a useful answer.

Answer (score 1):

This should be a comment, but I have insufficient rep for that.

The cause of the pattern is that your model doesn't account for something.

The fix is to find what that is, and include it in your model.